# Ionic button ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a set of buttons that will determine the amount of render pieces that will take place on the next view but I would like to make the buttons dynamic with an ng-repeat.
This is my code so far:

```
<button ion-button round block ng-repeat="item in [1, 2, 3, 4]">number!</button>
```

But this only renders 1 button. What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Angular 1.x` in `Ionic V1`

```
<button ion-button round block ng-repeat="item in [1, 2, 3, 4]  track by $index">number!</button>
```

For `Angular 4.x` in `Ionic V3`

```
<button ion-button round block *ngFor="#key of [1, 2, 3, 4]">number!</button>
```

Comment: Still prints only 1 :(

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something Ionic related

Comment: @Danubio: Which version do you use?

Comment: @Danubio: `ng-repeat` is just supported for `Angular 1.x` in `ionic v1`. Now you are using `Ionic v3` You need to follow structure of `angular 4`